# How do I fix UPnP Port Forwarding on Ubuntu using miniupnp?

Tags: networking, firewall, upnp

From what I understand, [Transmission bittorrent client](https://transmissionbt.com) uses the [miniupnp](http://miniupnp.tuxfamily.org/) library to do it's UPnP port forwarding of routers, however on Ubuntu upnpc (a test client of the miniupnp library) doesn't find any IDG routers, while on another Windows machine on the same networks it works correctly (with the windows binary of upnpc).

From what testing I've done, it seems that the `M-SEARCH SSDP` packet is not being sent onto the network, perhaps a firewall or something is stopping it.

How do I try and make sure these packets get though and this works?

Answer (score 1):

I just used [upnp-router-control](https://launchpad.net/upnp-router-control) to add a port forwarding to my router and it worked like a charm :)

If that doesn't work for you i would suggest you use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to analyze the network traffic and look where it hangs.

Comment: Just tried out upnp-router-control, the add/remove port mapping buttons are disabled for my router, although at least it does actually find it.

Comment: Then how about the wireshark test to see if there is some firewall at work blocking packages?

Answer (score 0):

Run in a shell to add config lines after fresh installed miniupnpd

```bsh
echo "MiniUPnPd_OTHER_OPTIONS=-N
START_DAEMON=1
MiniUPnPd_EXTERNAL_INTERFACE=eth0.4
MiniUPnPd_LISTENING_IP=eth0.1" | sudo tee -a /etc/default/miniupnpd; sudo service miniupnpd restart
```

Note: eth0.4 and eth0.1 is my ext/int interfaces, use yours.

Check chains after UPNP aware program restart:

```
sudo iptables -vnL MINIUPNPD ;sudo iptables -t nat -vnL MINIUPNPD
```

Should show few rules

All tested on Ubuntu 13.10.

All files at `/etc/miniupnpd/` just ignored.